# Is there an shorter or more direct way to set the value of this fontpicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the fontselector found [here](https://bitbucket.org/lindekleiv/jquery-ui-fontselector/src/f8196e52c014ae056eb089a3b8eb3a5fe873ae85/jquery.ui.fontSelector.js?at=master). I didn't see a way to manually set the font, so I came up w/ my own. Being a newb I was wondering if there's an easier way to manually set the selected font than what I have. I tried to make sense of their .js file but I couldn't figure it out to see if there's an easier way to do what I want.

[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nPmYD/) /// STACK OVERFLOW WOULDN'T LET ME POST THE JS links...see my fiddle

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>


/// STACK OVERFLOW WOULDN'T LET ME POST THE JS links...see my fiddle


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#fonts').fontSelector({
            fontChange: function(e, ui) {
                $('span.handle').html('&#9660;');
                $('ul.fonts').hide();
                $(".fonts").children().removeClass('selected'); // remove the "selected" class on everything
            }
           });

           $("#changeFont").on("click",function(){
               var selectedFont = "Ruda";
               $(".fonts").children().removeClass('selected');
               $(".fonts").find("li:contains(Ruda)").addClass('selected');
               $('div.fontSelector h4.selected').text("Ruda").css("font-family","Ruda");
           });
    });

    </script>

</head>


<body>

<button id="changeFont">Change Font</button>
<select id="fonts">
  <option value="Chelsea Market">Chelsea Market</option>
  <option value="Droid Serif" selected="selected">Droid Serif</option>
  <option value="Ruluko">Ruluko</option>
  <option value="Ruda">Ruda</option>
  <option value="Magra">Magra</option>
  <option value="Esteban">Esteban</option>
  <option value="Lora">Lora</option>
  <option value="Jura">Jura</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Better fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nPmYD/

Comment: Easier = shorter or more direct way than what I have